# Extract Text From Webpage and Save to Cell

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I would love some help as I've been struggling for over a week trying to find the answer. I have the following HTML and need to extract the total row number and save it to an Excel field.

```
<div class="vcr_controls">
<input>
<span class="sr-only">Showing rows 1 to 100 of 166</span>
<span class="list_row_number_input">to "
<span id="random id_last_row">100</span>
of "
<span id="random id_total_rows">166</span>
</span>
</div>
```

The VBA I have written is as follows:

```
Sub Test()
'/SET VARIABLES/
Dim loginPath as String
Dim totalRows as String
Dim IE as Object
LoginPath ="https:/domain.com/login"
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate loginPath
Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4
Loop
IE.Document.getElementByID("user_name").Value = "User"
IE.Document.getElementByID(user_password).Value = "Password"
'/SET VARIABLE AND REDIRECT
Dim cellURL as String
cellURL = Worksheet("Sheet1").Cells(2, "S").Value
loginPath = cellURL
IE.Navigate loginPath
Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4
Loop
'/NEED HELP HERE
Dim xobj
Set xobj = IE.Document.getElementById("vcr_controls").getElementsByClassName("list_row_input").Item(0)
Set xobj = xobj.getElementsByTagName("span").Item(1)
'/I CANNOT FIGURE OUT HOW TO EXTRACT THE TOTAL ROWS AND THEN SAVE THE NUMBER TO .Cells(2, "T")
```

Since the total_rows span tag has a random alphanumeric number generated I can't simply select it by the class name. The entire first part for the login works just fine.

Comment: I think you can do something that looks for partial string.  Try `...querySelectorAll("[id^='id_total_rows']")`

Comment: Hi, 
Thank you. I tried:

Dim xobj
Set xobj = IE.Document.querySelectorAll("[id^='id_total_rows']")
Dim var1 = xobj
MsgBox var1

The message box came up with the error:

[object NodeList]

Do I need to convert the object to a string when I use the Set command?

Comment: Ah - try `...querySelectorAll("[...]").innerText` to get the string.

Comment: I got this before when trying other methods but now the box displays:
[
Run-time error '438':
Object doesn't support this property or method
]
thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following CSS selector with `querySelector` which returns a single node.

```
ie.document.querySelector("span[id*='total_rows']").innerText
```

`querySelectorAll` returns a `nodeList` object which doesn't have an `.innerText` property. You would need to index into the `nodeList` and then use the `.innerText` on the retrieved node element. I wasn't sure if `id` was part of the id string value, if so, you could extend to:

```
ie.document.querySelector("span[id*='id_total_rows']").innerText
```

I have been overly verbose with the selector; possibly you might get away with simply:

```
ie.document.querySelector("[id$='total_rows']").innerText
```